# Locale ignores operation notation

Tags: isabelle

The following works fine:

```
class test1 = semilattice_sup +
  fixes x :: "'a"
  assumes "x < y"
```

But when I replace `class` by `locale`:

```
locale test2 = semilattice_sup +
  fixes x :: "'a"
  assumes "x < y"
```

I get the error:

```
Type unification failed: Variable 'a::type not of sort ord
```

The error can be fixed as follows:

```
locale test2 = semilattice_sup +
  fixes x :: "'a"
  assumes "less x y"
```

But is it possible to use `<` notation?

---

**UPDATE**

Here is a similar problem:

```
datatype 'a ty = A | B

instantiation ty :: (order) order
begin
definition "x < y ≡ x = A ∧ y = B"
definition "x ≤ y ≡ (x :: 'a ty) = y ∨ x < y"
instance
  apply intro_classes
  using less_eq_ty_def less_ty_def by auto
end

locale loc = semilattice_sup +
  fixes f :: "'a ⇒ 't :: order"
begin
definition "g ≡ inv f"
end

class cls = semilattice_sup +
  fixes f :: "'a ⇒ 'a ty"
begin
interpretation base: loc .
abbreviation "g ≡ base.g"
end
```

The interpretation fails with the following error:

```
Type unification failed: Variable 'a::type not of sort semilattice_sup
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would

```
locale test2 =
  fixes x :: "'a :: semilattice_sup"
  assumes "x < y"
```

be an option for you? In this case you no longer base your locale on another locale, but instead require the type of `x` to be an instance of the class `semilattice_sup`, which allows you to use nice infix syntax for `less`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It seems that everything works fine now. I've also experienced a related problem (please see an update in the question). And you solution fixed this problem too! I'm not an expert in Isabelle but it's very unintuitive for me why a derived locale doesn't derive a sort of `'a` from a base locale.

Comment: Answering the latter part of your comment, the point is exactly that the base local does *not* have a class and hence, because of the base local `'a` is only of class `type` (and is not even allowed to be further restricted later on). By dropping the dependency on the locale, we are able to instead depend on the corresponding class.